# Proxy class on client implements IExtensibleDataObject automatically

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

===
I'm new to this, but already having a problem.I have silverlight(5) application with wcf service reference on it. Before using VS2013,proxy class on client generated properly, without implementing IExtensibleDataObject on DataContract types.Now i want build this,after update service references, i taking a lot of errors, that VS cannot implement IExtensibleDataObject, because of it not in System.Runtime.Serialization assembly.

How i can evade implementation of IExtensibleDataObject on my types? In my understanding, silverlight does not support this interface and therefore i cannot build my app.

thanks

Comment: As far as I am aware, IExtensibleDataObject is still in the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace as of .NET 4.5. Is it that you do not have the required DLL referenced in your project?

Comment: Thanks. But silverlight is not .NET 4.5.It has same assemblies, but not fully of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'll have to manually invoke the slsvcutil.exe tool before the build phase as stated [here](http://sonyarouje.com/tag/iextensibledataobject-is-not-exist-in-system-runtime-serialization/), rather than the usual svcutil.exe that VS uses by default.

Another ugly hack you can use is having a script that runs between the WCF proxy generation step and the code build that removes the interface implementation and the field inside the proxy class.